# Switch statement unexpected result

Tags: java, switch-statement

I wrote this code but  it doesn't seem working. When we type `d`, it does the calculation for dollar but still doing (..what?).

Can you see + detect + in the list part, the part that is wrong?

```
String currency = sc.next();
        char detect = currency.charAt(0);
switch (detect){
    case 'D':
    case 'd':
        double dollar = (amount/18*10);
        System.out.println(amount + " Turkish Lira(s) --> " + dollar + " Dollar");

    case 'E':
    case 'e':
        double euro = (amount/23*10);
        System.out.println(amount + " --> " + euro + " Euro");

    case 'T':
    case 't':
        double lira = (amount);
        System.out.println(amount + " --> " + lira+ " Lira(s)");

        while (detect!='d'|| detect!='e' || detect!='t' || detect!='D'|| detect!='E' || detect!='T'){
            System.out.println("Can u See " + detect + " In The List ?\n" + menucur);
            currency = sc.next();
            detect = currency.charAt(0);
            } 
    }
```

Comment: A `switch` requires a `break;` at the end of each set of code statements, otherwise it will 'fall through'.

Comment: No reason to downvote here. A valid question with a clear-cut answer.

Comment: Check out [The switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: at the bottom of each case block - after your System.out lines in this example.

Comment: ok . now when i type d or t or e its fine.but first type the wrong letter l or ş for ex. after this even i enter d or t or e it istn workin

Comment: Your error message needs to be the `default:` case, makng the while test redundant, and the code to get the next character needs to be outside the `switch` altogether

Comment: Would ..any of the people who are down-voting this question care to share their reasoning?  Like @MarkoTopolnik, I find it quite mystifying.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `break` at the end of each case for your switch statement.

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: ok . now when i type d or t or e its fine.but first type the wrong letter l or ş for ex. after this even i enter d or t or e it istn workin

Comment: @user1810113: "it isn't working" is *never* enough information. Say what you did (exactly), what you expected to happen, and what happened.

Comment: This isn't really useful. ***Where*** in the `switch`?

Comment: first i type a letter that y or o or z whatever ( not d or t or e ).after that even i enter d it warns me can you see +detect + in the list ?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `break` at the end of each series of statements in each of your `case` blocks, e.g.:

```
switch (detect){
    case 'D':
    case 'd':
        double dollar = (amount/18*10);
        System.out.println(amount + " Turkish Lira(s) --> " + dollar + " Dollar");
        break; // <==== Add this

    case 'E':
    case 'e':
        double euro = (amount/23*10);
        System.out.println(amount + " --> " + euro + " Euro");
        break; // <==== Again here
```

...and so on. That tells the code that you don't want to carry on into the next `case`.

I recommend reading a good primer on Java. In the comments, MadProgrammer pointed to one tutorial specific to `switch`, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), but I'd take a step back and do a bit of a review of the basics.

Toward that end, here's an example of a properly-written `switch` statement:

```
// Assume `n` is an integer
switch (n) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        System.out.println("n is 0 or 1");
        break;

    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        System.out.println("n is 2, 3, or 4");
        break;

    case 17:
        System.out.println("n is 17");
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("n has some value other than 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 17");
        break;
}
```

Comment: it says unreachable code for while.if i write default : it goes underline code case 5 :

Comment: @user1810113: Your quoted code doesn't have a default case. If you mean the `while` loop to be the default case, put `default:` above it (and put the `break;` for the previous `case` above *that*). Again, though, I recommend stepping back and doing some reading before continuing on with this. This is basic stuff covered by any decent tutorial or primer.

Answer (score 1):

The necessary `beak` keyword is missing as Omar Jackman already pointed out. In addition, to handle invalid inputs (letters other than 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'T', 't' use the keyword `default`):

```
switch(case)
    case 'D':
    case 'd': 
         double dollar = (amount/18*10);
         System.out.println(amount + " Turkish Lira(s) --> " + dollar + " Dollar");
         break;

    case 'E':
    case 'e':
         double euro = (amount/23*10);
         System.out.println(amount + " --> " + euro + " Euro")
         break;

    //.. rest of your code
    // finally:

    default: // <- handle invalid letter input
         System.out.println("Invalid input");
         break;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. If this post answered your question mark is as answer: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not only the missing `break`, the flow of the logic also incorrect. The `switch` statement should be inside the `while` loop.

```
boolean done = false; 
while (!done){
   done = true;
   String currency = sc.next();
   char detect = currency.charAt(0);
   switch (detect){
      case 'D':
      case 'd':
         double dollar = (amount/18*10);
         System.out.println(amount + " Turkish Lira(s) --> " + dollar +
                           " Dollar");
         break;
      case 'E':
      case 'e':
         double euro = (amount/23*10);
         System.out.println(amount + " --> " + euro + " Euro");
         break;
      case 'T':
      case 't':
         double lira = (amount);
         System.out.println(amount + " --> " + lira+ " Lira(s)");
         break;
       default: 
         System.out.println(detect + " is not unknown\n");
         done = false;
    }
}
```